# How to set a whole GitHub Actions workflow as a required status check on a protected branch (instead of individual jobs)?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

The search bar for setting required status checks suggest only the names of individual jobs in workflows. They don't suggest the whole workflow.

This is inconvenient, because if I add a new job to the workflow, I would need to add this new job to the list of required status checks for the branch.

Is there a way of setting a whole GitHub Actions workflow as a required status check on a protected branch?

[image: GitHub protected branch status checks UI]

Answer (score 0):

you could use `workflow_run` to trigger your workflow like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["workflow1", "workflow2"]
    types:
      - completed
    branches:
      - main
```

More details in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)